# Laravel - How to send OneSignal notification using the external_user_id

Tags: laravel, onesignal

I'm trying to implement OneSignal in a Laravel application using this package. https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/onesignal

I'm saving the Laravel IDs into OneSignal DB using the [external_user_id](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/internal-database-crm) and it works properly. Now I'd like send a notification using the `external_user_id` but I cannot find any documentation about that.

Any advice? I guess I have to implement the `routeNotificationForOneSignal()`, but how? Returning the IDs I've stored in OneSignal doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `external_user_id` you have store the Laravel IDs into OneSignal DB, and then implement the `routeNotificationForOneSignal()` as follow... The `include_external_user_ids` will instruct OneSignal to use the `external_user_id`.

```php
namespace App;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * Get the notification routing information for the OneSignal driver.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function routeNotificationForOneSignal()
    {
        return ['include_external_user_ids' => [$this->id]];
    }
}
```